# Login by Moodle database

Tags: php, moodle

I have a moodle database(with full users in it). So, I want to create a login form (just for fun) and that users can login in with their moodle account credidentials. Moodle uses password salting for each individual user, how can I  salt the password in my code to compare with db record ?

Comment: Normally a new salt would be randomly generated for each created password (if they've implemented it in a standard way). So the salt may be stored in a separate column in the table, along with the password.

Comment: Or the salt is _part of_ the stored value already, in the way that `password_hash` and similar functions work.

Answer (score 2):

Moodle uses the default PHP function for password hashing (in modern non legacy version).
So to verify a password you can use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) if you don't care about supporting legacy versions.
Otherwise have a look at the [validate_internal_user_password](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/fc335f5ea0416a729af34f00bb4a8e1fbb287e54/lib/moodlelib.php#L4607) function in the Moodle source code